# WIFI 6 Card not working even though the computer detects it and up to date drivers are installed

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, network-adapter, computer-building

I have run into a dead end here. I am trying to install an Intel AX200 WIFI + Bluetooth network card onto my desktop PC. I connected it to a PCIe port that had more slots than needed but I read that this should be fine. Additionally, a cable from the network card was connected to one of the USB inputs of the mainboard for the Bluetooth. My problem is that I never got the WIFI to work (only the Bluetooth).

**What I tried on windows**:
On Windows, the device is found in the device manager. I have installed the newest drivers and later checked if they are up to date using the [Intel Driver Support Assistant](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28425/Intel-Driver-Support-Assistant). The Bluetooth drivers instantly functioned as intended. However, the WIFI drivers never really worked. I tried reinstalling them a couple of times. Sometimes they did not work at all (`Code 10` error in device manager), sometimes there were no errors and it even showed some of the available wifi networks, but I could not connect to them.

**What I tried on Ubuntu**: To further trace the error I also tried the same things on Ubuntu. Here the drivers installed automatically with the system update and I am on an up to date kernel `version 5.3.0-42-generic`. I also found the up to date drivers (same as on [Intel's download page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html?productId=189347&localeCode=us_en)) in `/lib/firmware`. By all means, it feels like I have the up to date drivers installed. `lshw -C network` returns the following

```
   description: Network controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 1a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:f0100000-f0103fff

   ....other network devices follow...
```

This also looks like the drivers are properly installed? Now I am wondering what I may have missed/done wrong. Of course, it is suspicious that the WiFi neither works on Windows nor on Ubuntu. The WiFi works when using another USB-WiFi Dongle.

[This is what I see when trying to start WIFI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bi6i.png)

- Could it be that [my mainboard](https://www.asrock.com/mb/intel/B85M%20Pro4/index.de.asp) does not support WIFI 6? Or does
  basically every mainboard support WIFI 6 if you connect the proper
  network card to it?
- Maybe I did not properly install the network card into the PCIe slot (I have no experience in installing computer parts). Then again, it looks like I can only install the card in this orientation. Could it still be installed wrong even if it already shows up on both Windows and Ubuntu?
- What else could be causing problems?

Thank you guys for any help!

---

**EDIT**

So in the device manager I usually find the following errors. First, I get an error 430 (device needs more installations), then an error 400 with the following info (I tried translating):

```
The device PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2723&SUBSYS_00848086&REV_1A\4&63638ad&0&0008 was configured.

driver name: oem20.inf
class-GUID: {4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
driver data: 02/25/2020
driver version: 21.80.2.1
driver producer: Intel
driver part: Install_MPCIEX_GENM21_200_AX_2x2_HMC_WINT_64_AX
driver rank: 0xFC0001
matching device-id: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_2723&SUBSYS_00848086
device with lowest rank: 
**device was updatet: false**
Superordinated device: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0C01&SUBSYS_0C011849&REV_06\3&11583659&0&08
```

I marked the 'device was update: false' line because it sounds suspicious. After this, I get an error 411 (there was a problem when starting the device).

```
Treibername: oem20.inf
Klassen-GUID: {4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Dienst: Netwtw08
Untere Filter: 
Obere Filter: vwifibus
Problem: 0xA
Problemstatus: 0xC0000001
```

By now I have so often uninstalled/reinstalled the drivers on windows that I really fear that I might have corrupted something. Can I get a more clean deinstallation of drivers then simply deleting them in the device manager?

**Edit 2**

Running Ubuntu `dmesg |grep iwl`, I found a long list of error dumps for the iwlwifi (that's the right device/driver). I of course tried googling and understand them but can't yet make any sense of them.

```
2.501969] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    2.501973] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.501975] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.502243] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.546727] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    2.557738] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.558114] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    3.569736] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    3.569815] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    3.569818] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 6
[    3.569820] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 48.4fa0041f.0
[    3.569822] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[    3.569823] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0020A2F0 | trm_hw_status0
[    3.569825] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    3.569826] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F8E3C | branchlink2
[    3.569827] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E4FF4 | interruptlink1
[    3.569829] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E4FF4 | interruptlink2
[    3.569830] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F3DB0 | data1
[    3.569831] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00001000 | data2
[    3.569832] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xF0000000 | data3
[    3.569833] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    3.569834] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00008C13 | tsf low
[    3.569835] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    3.569837] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    3.569838] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000EF36 | time gp2
[    3.569840] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[    3.569841] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000030 | uCode version major
[    3.569842] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4FA0041F | uCode version minor
[    3.569844] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000340 | hw version
[    3.569845] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00C89000 | board version
[    3.569846] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x8002FF03 | hcmd
[    3.569848] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x20020000 | isr0
[    3.569849] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[    3.569850] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x08F00002 | isr2
[    3.569852] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[    3.569853] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    3.569854] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[    3.569855] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F3DB0 | wait_event
[    3.569856] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[    3.569858] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000020 | l2p_duration
[    3.569859] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    3.569860] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    3.569862] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    3.569863] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[    3.569864] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000F81C | flow_handler
[    3.569889] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    3.569890] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[    3.569892] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x201000A3 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    3.569893] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    3.569895] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC008CC3C | umac branchlink2
[    3.569896] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0087660 | umac interruptlink1
[    3.569898] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[    3.569899] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data1
[    3.569900] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
[    3.569902] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[    3.569903] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000030 | umac major
[    3.569904] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4FA0041F | umac minor
[    3.569906] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000EF2A | frame pointer
[    3.569907] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0886C1C | stack pointer
[    3.569909] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000FFFF | last host cmd
[    3.569910] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    3.569916] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[    3.569919] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x20000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    3.569923] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80290001 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    3.569926] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    3.569929] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    3.569933] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    3.569936] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    3.569939] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    3.569942] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    3.569945] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    3.569950] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    3.569956] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    3.569961] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    3.569978] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x614c, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[    3.569980] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    3.569983] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    3.581765] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Comment: Just a thought, not a solution by any means: Have you checked into BIOS/UEFI if there's not something to activate first? I don't AsRock mobos very well, but I know they usually come with many options to customize peripherals. Plus, in Windows, have you checked Power saving options in both Device manager and Network (in the adapter properties); while you're at it, in the Details tab, does it give off any error code or not fully installed driver warning?

Comment: If you were able to see Wi-Fi networks, then the card and drivers were most likely working. Did you remember to attach the antennas? The most common reason for seeing a Wi-Fi network but being unable to connect (assuming you got the password right) is low signal strength.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I will check all of this and add information to the post. The antennas seem to be properly attatched.

Comment: I found nothing in the UEFI settings that seems to have something to with the network card :/

Comment: @daudprobst: I meant "peripherals", namely PCIe ones. Nothing about how the mobo is powering them, power saving settings or anything? Legacy mode (if such a thing exists for PCIe equipment)?

Comment: I actually found a menu regarding ACPI Configuration, but the only setting that sounds close to PCI is "PCI Devices Power On, which allows/disallows for PCI devices to wake up the system (I tried both settings). There are many power settings regarding the CPU as well. I also found  an error dump in the Ubuntu dmesg that I added to the post that might help to further trace the error.

Comment: Have you tried running Snappy Driver Installer (https://sdi-tool.org/)?